# In this IronPython example what is the @ symbol doing and how is it implemented?

Tags: c#, ironpython

http://www.ironpython.info/index.php/Using_Python_Classes_from_.NET/CSharp_IP_2.6

```
   string code = @"
   print 'test = ' + test
   class MyClass:
       def __init__(self):
           pass

       def somemethod(self):
           print 'in some method'

       def isodd(self, n):
           return 1 == n % 2
   ";
```

Is that '@' part of C# or is that something added by IronPython? If the latter, how do you do that in C#, some kind of operator overloading (basically could I then make '@' do whatever I want, etc)? Example implementation would be great. Otherwise, what's going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@""` is a [verbatim string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx) in C#.  That is, escape characters inside it are not interpreted.

In this case, the python code is being stored in the C# `code` string variable, and then is compiled into a `CompiledCode` from a `ScriptSource` using a `ScriptEngine` (which is itself created using `Python.CreateEngine()`).

Answer (score 0):

The @ is part of the C# code. It means that the string is a [verbatim string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28VS.71%29.aspx). The string holds the Python code to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

```
string path = @"C:\Sweet\now\I\can\use\backslashes\without\writing\them\all\twice.txt"
```